# Gitlab shows remote: This server is readonly

Tags: gitlab

Can't push the changes to any existing repository (Or) to new repository.

**Error while pushing the changes:-**

```
git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 226 bytes | 226.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: ================================================
remote: This server is readonly
remote: ================================================
To gitlab.domain.com:gitlab-user/test30-jan-2020.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.domain.com:gitlab-user/test30-jan-2020.git'
```

`GitLab GUI --> Under Admin--> Settings-->General & Repository settings checked`, seems settings are fine.

And GitLab Server `gitlab.rb` file also doesn't have **readonly** settings mode enabled.

Any other clue/input to enable write mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side there was a custom hook `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/pre-receive.d` which was preventing the push. Same has been removed it started working.